# Usage of "to be done" with "work"

Tags: verbs

What are the differences between the following and when do we use them?

1. There is still **work to be done**.
2. The **work has to be done**.
3. The **work is to be done**.

Comment: *Work* is a noun, and the same in all your sentences. What are you actually asking here? (Please edit the question or its title to make that clear, don't add a comment explaining it)

Comment: You might also find [ell.se] useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number 1 isn't a complete sentence, it's a noun phrase. It refers to work. What work? The work that is to be done. At the start of a project, somebody might observe that there's a lot of *work to be done*

Number 2 is a sentence that states an obligation. There is work to be done, and somebody has got to do it.

Number 3 is a sentence about intent (although it's unlikely to stand alone). It is pretty much equivalent to "work will be done". "We have almost finished the roof. Further work is to be done on Monday."